# Removing old fashioned saddle from seatpost

Tags: seatpost

I've been searching for instructions on how to remove my old saddle from my seatpost. All the videos/guides I've seen have been about the newer kind of clamping mechanism where just one bolt needs to be loosened with an allen wrench. Mine is different- there are two bolts on either side of the saddle and none of my tools seem to fit. (It's an HL Aluminum Micro Adjust 27.2 X 300mm). How can I remove it??

Comment: A photo would be helpful. Is it similar to this one: http://www.totalbike.rs/delovi/sedista/selne/spojnica-sipke-i-sedista-klobna

Comment: From a few (unclear) pictures of bikes with that clamp it *appears* to be a variation of the old style similar to Mladen's link.  Basically you have nuts on either side and you loosen those with a standard socket or open-end wrench.  But they could have "sexed it up" with some other style bolt, I suppose -- the pictures simply aren't clear enough.

Comment: I picked up a Bridgestone MB-2 at a garage sale for $5. I would like to replace the giant seat with a smaller one. I can't figure out how to make the new one attach with the old seat post.

Answer (score 2):

I found that the GMC Denali 21 speed uses an HL Aluminum Micro Adjust 27.2 X 300mm, so I assume your seat is very similar to those found on the Denali. In this case you will need a small crescent wrench that will fit between the guts and the side of the saddle. Some bolts are square and will stay put when loosing the nuts, but some are not and might require an opposing wrench on the other side. You only need to loosen each side a half turn and you can slide the seat off the post. The problem is that you will only be able to replace it with similar guts. You might be able to swap out the saddle itself if the rails match, but my recommendation would be to switch the whole saddle/post with a more modern set.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Get 2 spanners that fit. Hold the bolts on both sides with the spanners and turn any one side to remove easily.

To put it back alternately rotate each side 1 or 2 turns.
Be careful with the tightness, if it's slightly loose you'll experience slight play in the saddle and the micro adjust assembly will soon get worn out. Too tight and you might deform your saddle rails.

You will get a spanner, just look for it in a hardware store or get adjustable ones.

I had a similar setup on my Bridgestone. Mine was a lot more antiquated as the seat post had a bolt mechanism similar to a handlebar stem :)